# Where would the commas go in "I am too tired to think clearly"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I don't know where the commas would go in:

> I am too tired to think clearly.

I think it should be:

> I am, too, tired to think clearly.

Am I correct?

Comment: Title of the question needs to be improved as "Where would the commas go in 'I am too tired to think clearly'?"

Comment: @PlasmaStarfish Very clever.  But inappropriate for retorts to low-rep posters.

Comment: Hi, Seth. Bear in mind that _too_ may not require any commas at all in certain situations—so you might want to include that possibility in your presentation of the example sentence.

Answer (score 1):

### No.

"Too" in this case means "overly" and not "also". The meaning is

> I am so tired that I cannot think clearly

and not

> I am also tired and cannot think clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "I am, too," is okay, if you mean "I, as well as someone else", but then something else is needed after "too," -- perhaps "I am, too, too tired to think clearly".

But if you mean "It is clear that I am too tired to think", that would be "I am too tired to think, clearly" because "clearly" is a sentence adverb, whose normal position is at the beginning ("Clearly I am too tired to think"), so at the end, a comma is required.

With no comma, "clearly" would be interpreted as a manner adverb: "I am too tired to think clearly (= in a clear manner)".